# Georgia Font not displaying in FireFox (but is fine in all other browsers)?

Tags: firefox, fonts, font-face

So Ive set my website to use this font stack:

```
Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif
```

And Ive tested this in Chrome, Internet Explorer and Safari - and they all display the first font in the stack, Georgia.

But Firefox skips Georgia and displays Times New Roman. Now that Ive noticed this on my site, Ive also noticed this in all other websites thru Firefox - it simply doesnt like the Georgia Font.

The font is installed on my machine and works fine in all my other programs (including Word and Photoshop).

Anybody have a clue as to why FireFox has fallen out with the Georgia Font?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps Georgia is missing or corrupted and Firefox replace it with a different one.

You can make a test to identify corrupted font(s):
http://browserspy.dk/fonts-flash.php?detail=1

Comment: if it was missing or corrupted why would it work fine in every other application on my computer?

Comment: I think about a specific rendering with FF and corrupted font. But if font is ok you can try disabling graphics hardware acceleration (providing some glitches like font rendering).

Comment: Re-installed the Georgia font and this fixed my problems in FF. Thanks jerome!